# How to interpret class definitions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am relativelly new to Python (I have finished few courses and now I am doing some exercices). I am trying to understand how to interpret class definitions. Let me explain.

So I want to use built in dict() function. Obviously I know that it will produce a dictionary, but I am trying to deduce and conclude in what way I should pass the arguments. Easiest is of course to do a web search and see the example, but again, I am trying to conclude how.

In this specific case, peek definition (if that's how you call it) looks like this:[image]

While example is also provided in the last line, I am trying to understand the following line (first one):

```
iterable: Iterable[Tuple[_KT, _VT]], **kwargs: _VT)
```

By understand this line, I should be able to understand other similar class definitiions in the future.

Comment: `dict` is a very unusual class/function in that it can take three very different kinds of arguments. I would not use this as a starting point for learning about class definitions and function signatures.

Comment: Also, that's not what the actual class definition looks like (the actual class definition is written in C), and it doesn't even resemble what the definition *would* look like if `dict` wasn't written in C. It's got constructor parameters where the superclasses are supposed to go.

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks for the reply, but I would still like to understand it. I guess it's one of those things which will become more clear in time, as I learn along the way.

user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the reply, my terminology was not 100% correct, I am still learning it. Apparently, my question should have been how to interpret class signatures?

Comment: `: Iterable[Tuple[_KT, _VT]]` is a *type hint*, and you can google that if you want to learn more about them. The most important thing to know is that they are just hints - they're entirely optional and don't affect how the program runs.